# Large Movie Review Dataset

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nlp, logistic-regression, imdb

can anyone help me with an assignment? It's about doing linear regression from scratch on imdb reviews.
the data is really heavy and also, I don't understand the assignment itself really well
I did some of it but I have some major problem with implementing the logistic regression from scratch on the data.

Comment: You can't use SO to solve your homework. Start working on the assignment, when you get genuinely stuck ask a more specific question after showing what you've tried

Comment: @Jackie see ["_How do I ask and answer homework questions?_"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/20170164). Of course, that is totally separate from whatever policy your school has with using resources like SO for homework.

Comment: I don't know much of anything about logistic regression, but I get a feeling this question post has nowhere near enough detail to be a good fit for SO. Please take a look at [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jackie Mr./Mrs., I would appreciate it if you would stop being so judgmental about people you know nothing about them. I am sorry that I did not ask my question so clearly but with all respect, I do not need to hear something like this from a person who is a complete stranger and does not know me AT ALL.
Regards

Comment: @rainbow.gekotaThank you. I'll try to clarify my question.

Answer (score 0):

IMDb seems to have an API https://developer.imdb.com/

Maybe not what you are looking for exactly, but might lead you in the right direction

I also found this datased on kaggle listing movie reviews, also from IMDb.

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lakshmi25npathi/imdb-dataset-of-50k-movie-reviews

So IMDb might be a good place to start looking

Comment: I already have the dataset, it's a special format of imdb reviews but I need help for doing tasks on this dataset

Comment: Then you really would need to provide some additional information on the details about the assigment itself, if you do, i could try to provide a better answer